# How to include argument with CreateProcess API in VC++?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have called the other application from my main application using createprocess API. But the other process also need some arguments as a parameter.

I created the process as:

```
BOOL ret= CreateProcess( NULL, szCmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL,&siStartInfo, &piProcInfo);
```

szCmdline is variable which contians the application full path.

Any idea how to pass the argument with this process.

Thanks,

Comment: MSDN for CreateProcess() is quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form a string consisting of program name + arguments like this

```
wstring cmd;
cmd.assign(L"\"C:\\Program Files\\MyProgram.exe\"  arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4");
if(!CreateProcess(NULL,(LPWSTR)cmd.c_str(),NULL,NULL,1,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi))
{
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: -1 You just casted yourself into an access violation. [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx): *"If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation."* Whenever you need a cast, you're doing it wrong. True story.

Comment: An AV occurs if the second parameter points at read-only memory, like a compile-time literal. In this case, it is being passed a pointer to runtime-allocated memory. Ignore the fact that `c_str()` returns a `const` pointer. The memory it is actually pointing at is not read-only memory. The type-cast (`const_cast` would be better) is merely to remove the `const`-ness from the pointer at compile-time since `CreateProcess()` does not accept a `const` pointer, but that does not change the fact that the memory is still writable at runtime, so `CreateProcess()` can safely write to it without an AV.

Comment: @Remy There are `std::wstring` implementations out in the wild that implement copy-on-write. For these kind of beasts the underlying memory in the code above is not writable - it still points to the character literal when `c_str()` is invoked. Using `WCHAR cmd[] = L"blah";` on the other hand is safe. And does not require a cast. Using a `std::wstring` for the sake of using a `std::wstring` is questionable. And dangerous.

Answer (score 5):

CreateProcess has both lpApplicationName and szCommandLine arguments. You must pass at least one of the arguments. However you should pass both for security reasons.

- `lpApplicationName` is the name of the executable you wish to run.
- `szCommandLine` is the command line you wish to pass to that executable. It should include the executable as the first item. This will be received by the application as an argument to `WinMain` or retrieved by the `GetCommandLine` function (though the system may prepend a fully-qualified path if one is not supplied). For C programs using `main` or `wmain`, it will be parsed by the CRT into arguments.
- If you pass `NULL` for `lpApplicationName`, the system will attempt to locate the executable in `szCommandLine`, and will use that.
- If you pass NULL for `szCommandLine`, the system will use `lpApplicationName` for both.

So the command line is the command line. If you have arguments to pass to the command, put them on the command line.

> If lpApplicationName is NULL, the first white space–delimited token of
>   the command line specifies the module name. If you are using a long
>   file name that contains a space, use quoted strings to indicate where
>   the file name ends and the arguments begin (see the explanation for
>   the lpApplicationName parameter).

It is preferable to pass both lpApplicationName and szCommandLine, to ensure that the command line is not misinterpreted by the system and the wrong executable is run. (There was a class of security problems caused by this a few years ago).

Also, when passing both lpApplicationName and szCommandLine, remember that szCommandLine still needs to include the application name as the first argument.

So for instance, if your program is `C:\Program Files\My Application\Program.exe` and the arguments are `/the /arguments`, you would set lpApplicationName to `"C:\Program Files\My Application\Program.exe"`, and set `szCmdline` to `"C:\Program Files\My Application\Program.exe" /the /arguments`.

What were the security concerns?

Well imagine if someone created a file "C:\Program Files\My.exe". If you omit the quotes, the system interpreted `C:\Program Files\My Application\Program.exe /the /arguments` as: `C:\Program Files\My.exe Application\Program.exe /the /arguments`. And you will get a surprise. This type of trick can be used to fool administrators into running programs they did not wish to run, which is a security problem. This does not occur if you pass the lpApplicationName argument.

Comment: @Ben: That was rather a dramatic edit. Maybe you should post your own answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The CreateProcess function creates a new process, which runs independently of the creating process. However, for simplicity, the relationship is referred to as a parent-child relationship.
The first parameter, lpApplicationName, can be NULL, in which case the executable name must be in the white space–delimited string pointed to by lpCommandLine.

this way you can send more than one arguments in CreateProcess  API.

```
sprintf(exePath,"Project.exe %s %s \"%s\" \"%s\" \", appName,serverid,srjPath,caseName);

    if( !CreateProcess( NULL, // No module name (use command line).
        exePath,      // Command line.
        NULL,                 // Process handle not inheritable.
        NULL,                 // Thread handle not inheritable.
        FALSE,                // Set handle inheritance to FALSE.
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,// No creation flags.
        NULL,                 // Use parent's environment block.
        NULL,                 // Use parent's starting directory.
        &si,                  // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure.
        &pi )                 // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.
        )
```

when revived this command line arguments you should parsing this argument and separated by
A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash, \", is interpreted as a literal double quotation mark (").

for parsing command line argument visit this site : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx

and creatprocess API visit this :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(Ex). The Control is much simpler, and since we have UAC the Control how to Launch a process is easier to.

With ShellExecuteEx aou also get the process handle if you Need it.

Just my 2 Cents.

Comment: The COM part is a PITA.

Comment: COM? Where does ShellExecute use COM?

Comment: Read your link. *Remarks
Because ShellExecute can delegate execution to Shell extensions (data sources, context menu handlers, verb implementations) that are activated using Component Object Model (COM), COM should be initialized before ShellExecute is called. Some Shell extensions require the COM single-threaded apartment (STA) type. In that case, COM should be initialized as shown here:*

Comment: And if we just execute an EXEit isn'nt needed. We are just talking about to Launch a simple EXE!

Comment: Yes, let's ignore Microsoft's specific guidance on this matter: *There are certainly instances where ShellExecute does not use one of these types of Shell extension and those instances would not require COM to be initialized at all. Nonetheless, it is good practice to always initalize COM before using this function.*

Comment: @xMRi You seem to not have fully grasped the documentation. We are **not** talking about *"just launching a simple EXE"*. We are talking about the shell and how it implements `ShellExecuteEx`. The shell is a minefield. If you can find a core OS API that does what you need, use that instead.